# SQL query for multiple tables with one SELECT statement using variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables

I'm pretty new to SQL, but given the below example is there a way to condense the query? From my understanding SQL does not have arrays, but is it possible to store the tables somehow and do one SELECT statement, as maybe a variable (Select Count(*) From Table_Name) As Table_Name)?

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ActivityLog) AS ActivityLog,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ActivityLogin) AS ActivityLogin,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ActivityPlayContent) AS ActivityPlayContent,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ChangeLog) AS ChangeLog,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ContentApprovalLog) AS ContentApprovalLog,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ExceptionLog) AS ExceptionLog,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM State) AS State
```

Comment: You could define a stored procedure which dynamically constructs and then executes a SQL string query like the one you have above, but this is pretty much how SQL works.  Dynamically constructing it as an SP is something akin to programming (with a language well not built for it)

Comment: Check [this link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2537/sql-server-row-count-for-all-tables-in-a-database/), there are different ways to generate count for tables, you can pick one and modify it and write a function/stored procedure to work for the tables you want counts for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need this query often and want to have it simpler, you can create a [VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-view.html).
You then have to query the view like you query a table.

```
SELECT * FROM MyView
```

Views are especially helpful when you have multiple complex queries and you want to reuse them in other queries (f.e. joining two views together or subquerying a view).

Create the view for your query as follows

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ActivityLog) AS ActivityLog,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ActivityLogin) AS ActivityLogin,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ActivityPlayContent) AS ActivityPlayContent,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ChangeLog) AS ChangeLog,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ContentApprovalLog) AS ContentApprovalLog,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ExceptionLog) AS ExceptionLog,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM State) AS State
```

Comment: A good point, well made, but it doesn't really answer the question?

Comment: I agree that stored procedures would address this more directly, but I don't want to teach a SQL beginner to put everything in SP as this wouldn't be good. Given that his intention is to make the query more condensed, a view solves this problem in a smarter way.

Comment: The OP's question is asking how to write this without having to supply specific table names. In other words, he probably wants to write something dynamic based on `sys.objects` - as highlighted in the link in the comment from @rs.

Comment: I started researching into stored procedures and it seems like it would be similar to a C# method that can be called with parameters. I have to dive in a bit more.

Comment: Ok, I setup both a view and stored procedure. The stored procedure was a little tricky and it's not 100 percent yet, but I think I got it. Thanks!